# Bounds for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\ln(i)}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Consider for $n\geq1$:

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\ln(i)}$$

It seems to be hard to give an exact formula for this.

> For large $n$, are there good bounds one can get for $S_n$?

Ideally I would like bounds written in elementary terms so I can understand their asymptotics.

---

**Update**

It is straightforward to see that $n^{\ln(n)} \leq S_n \leq n^{\ln(n)+1}$.  However, is $S_n$ asymptotic to some constant times the lower or upper bound or something in between?

[Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271193/asymptotic-growth-of-sum-i-1n-i-lni]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, *it seems to be hard to give an exact formula for this.*
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\log(i)}$$

Computing a few values reproduced below for $\log(S_n)$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \log(S_n) \\
 100 & 23.5591 \\
 200 & 30.9636 \\
 300 & 35.7524 \\
 400 & 39.3537 \\
 500 & 42.2632 \\
 600 & 44.7156 \\
 700 & 46.8417 \\
 800 & 48.7224 \\
 900 & 50.4113 \\
 1000 & 51.9458
\end{array}
\right)$$ and plotting them, it seems that they look like $$\log(S_n)=a\, n^b+c$$ Performing a nonlinear regression, the following is obtained
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error}  \\
 a & 28.7896  & 0.77787  \\
 b & 0.164932 & 0.00226  \\
 c & -37.9895 & 1.03575  \\
\end{array}$$ corresponding to  a quite good fit of the data ($R^2$ almost equal to $1$) .

Extrapolating is always dangerous : using this model, $\log(S_{2000})=62.8620$ while the correct value should be $62.6013$ which is not too bad (I hope).

**Edit**

Inspired by OmG's answer, we could use $$\int_1^n x^{\log(x)}\,dx=n^{\log (n)+1} F\left(\log (n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)-F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears  the Dawson integral.

**Update**

We have the double inequality $$n^{\log(n)} < S_n <n^{1+\log(n)}$$ Considering $T_n=\frac{S_n}{n^{\log(n)}}$ and curve fitting $T_n$ for the range $10^2 < n <10^4$,an approximation could be $$T_n=0.133133\,n^{0.89683}+3.14905$$For example, using $n=10^4$, this approximation gives $S_n=3.59432\times 10^{39}$ while the exact value should be $S_n=3.59626\times 10^{39}$

Similarly,for infinitely large values of $x$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)), $$F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k+1} x^{2k+1}}
 = \frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{1}{4 x^3} + \frac{3}{8 x^5}+O\left(\frac 1{x^7} \right) $$ Limiting the the first term, this would make  $$\int_1^n x^{\log(x)}\,dx\approx \frac{n^{1+\log (n)}}{2 \log (n)+1}$$ For example, using $n=10^4$, this last approximation gives for the integral $=3.57353\times 10^{39}$ while its exact value  should be $3.59279\times 10^{39}$. For sure, adding more terms will make the approximation better.

Comment: Is $F(\log(n) + 1/2)$ greater than or less than $1$?

Comment: @Lembik. It is less than $1$ but $n F\left(\log (n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ looks like a straight line with  a small positive slope. For $n=1000$, this term is "just" $\approx 68.13$

Comment: What is $F(1/2)$ approximately?

Comment: @Lembik. Almost $0.4244$

Comment: Are the asymptotics of $n F(\log{n} +1/2)$ known?

Comment: What I mean is, is it known that $nF(\log{n} + 1/2) \sim cn$ for some small constant $c>0$?

Comment: From plotting the function the "constant" seems to carry on decreasing. I got it down to about $3/100$ so far.

Comment: nice (+1), maybe we can employ euler mac-laurin to make this rigorous?

Comment: @Lembik. Please, have a look to my update.

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound could be like the following:

$$\int x^{ln(x)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} erfi(\log{x}+0.5)}{2e^{0.25}}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{ln(i)}\leq \int_1^n x^{ln(x)}dx \leq \frac{\sqrt{\pi} erfi(\log{n}+0.5)}{2e^{0.25}}$$

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer just related to the bounds.*
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\ln(i)}=1+\sum_{i=2}^n i^{\ln(i)}$$ Since $x^{\log(x)}$ is increasing for $x \geq 1$ then $$I_n=\int_{x=1}^nx^{\log(x)} \leq\sum_{i=2}^n i^{\ln(i)}\leq J_n=\int_{x=2}^{n+1}x^{\log(x)}\,dx$$ whith make
$$I_n+1 \leq S_n\leq J_n+1$$ (this holds for any $n >2$) using 
$$I_n+1=n^{\log (n)+1} F\left(\log (n)+\frac{1}{2}\right)-F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+1$$ $$J_n+1= (n+1)^{\log (n+1)+1} F\left(\log (n+1)+\frac{1}{2}\right)-2^{1+\log (2)}
   F\left(\frac{1}{2}+\log (2)\right)+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $S_n := \sum_{ i =1}^n e^{\log(i)^2}$. For $k$ that is small compared to $n$, consider the contribution to the sum from the term with $i = n-k$. Here we have
\begin{align*}
\log(n-k)^2 = \log(n)^2 - 2 \frac{\log n }{n}k + O(k^2/n^2).
\end{align*}
In particular, we anticipate that for large $n$
\begin{align*}
S_n = (1 + o(1)) e^{ \log(n)^2 } \sum_{ k \geq 1} e^{ - 2 \frac{\log n}{n} k }.
\end{align*}
Now using the fact that for small $\varepsilon$, $\sum_{ k \geq 1} e^{ - \varepsilon k } \approx 1/\varepsilon$, it seems reasonable to guess that
\begin{align*}
S_n = (1 + o(1)) e^{ \log(n)^2 } \frac{n}{2 \log n }.
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$.